# notepad++ add characters in the middle of string

Tags: notepad++

I'm having a data file that would require adding commas in the middle of specific lines. e.g. line with indicator 156 in the examples below.

This is a snippet from the actual data. the numbers are not line numbers but indicators in the actual data. The indicator numbers repeat in sequences so I would need to change every 156: (among some other)

```
153:0
154:0
155:132
156:5808
157:0
```

Should look like:

```
153:0
154:0
155:132
156:58,08
157:0
```

Is there a possibility to do this handily with notepad++ os should I start making some additional scripts. The amount of data is quite massive but this transformation is a one time operation only.

Comment: will you make it clear, I don't get what your want.

Comment: just 156:5808 -> 156:58,08, or else ? gobal search and replace.

Comment: I don't think is the best tool to do specific line treatment. If you are proficient with any script language, you should try. Maybe with awk...

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not too clear with my example. the line 156: contains amount in cents. in the future it is required in Dollars with cents separated by comma (5808 -> 58,08) The amounts will vary through the file as the line 156: repeats. I'm not an expert with scripting so probably takes more time to make the script than do the work manually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your needs, this should do what you want:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(156:\d\d)(\d\d)`
- Replace with: `$1,$2`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>